# Adding xml file to the project folders after the program is packaged

Tags: c#

I have the following code which pass data from datagridview to a xml file (stored in my device in this path: this path: C:\Users\Multi\MainPro\bin\Debug) and then display them in crystal report, the application is working fine as long as I run it from my device but it doesn't work in user device, so How can I fix this problem?

````
           DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
           Dt.Columns.Add("BrachName", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachNO", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachType", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachGroupName", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachChasiNO", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachFeatures", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachCountry", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachModel", typeof(int));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachIsOff", typeof(Boolean));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachIsloaning", typeof(Boolean));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachIsBorrowed", typeof(Boolean));
           Dt.Columns.Add("MachNotes", typeof(string));
           Dt.Columns.Add("Clarefication", typeof(string));
           foreach (DataGridViewRow dgv in dgMachines.Rows)
           {
               Dt.Rows.Add(dgv.Cells[0].Value, dgv.Cells[1].Value, dgv.Cells[2].Value, dgv.Cells[3].Value, dgv.Cells[4].Value, dgv.Cells[5].Value, dgv.Cells[6].Value, dgv.Cells[7].Value, dgv.Cells[8].Value, dgv.Cells[9].Value,dgv.Cells[10].Value, dgv.Cells[11].Value, dgv.Cells[12].Value);
           }
           Ds.Tables.Add(Dt);
           Ds.WriteXmlSchema("Sample.xml");

           RPT.RPT_DG myreport = new RPT.RPT_DG();
           myreport.SetDataSource(Ds);
           RPT.FRM_Reports myform = new RPT.FRM_Reports();
           myform.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
           myform.ShowDialog();```
````

Comment: Kindly describe the problem to be able to understand it better. What steps you have taken to remediate/analyze so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing to another folder. You can use `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` as a place to write your file to.

Maybe this link will help:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295866/program-cant-find-file-after-install/13296809#13296809)