# Retrieving records from SQL Server CE [is anybody on this planet can solve this issue??]

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have included database in my project(at root).

The connection string

```
Data Source=|DataDirectory|\TSM_DB.sdf;Password=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;Max Database Size=512
```

`TSM_DB.sdf` properties:

- Build Action = Content
- Copy to Output Directory = Copy if newer

Dataset properties:

- Build Action = None
- Copy to Output Directory = Do Not Copy

**My problem:**

When I try to insert data into the database it gets inserted to the database present in **Debug folder** and not in the database which is included in the project...

And that’s why (obviously) my select statement does not find any record in the database (according to my connection string)...

I think the query (code) is perfectly fine, but some sort of settings need be done.

How do I solve this issue?

**EDIT :**

Example Select Code (working : when connection string path is Absolute)

```
Try
        Dim cnt_temp
        Dim SQLquery As String
        Dim myConString As String = My.Settings.TSM_DBConnectionString
        con.ConnectionString = myConString
        SQLquery = "SELECT * FROM tbl_outward"
        Dim DA As SqlCeDataAdapter, Ds As New DataSet, Dtb As New System.Data.DataTable
        DA = New SqlCeDataAdapter(SQLquery, con)
        DA.Fill(Ds)
        Dtb = Ds.Tables(0)
        cnt_temp = Dtb.Rows.Count
        MsgBox(cnt_temp)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error..!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
```

Comment: No, your connection string contains |DataDirectory| that is a substitution string and for WInForms application is the BIN\DEBUG directory when running inside Visual Studio and the current directory when your program runs standalone. I think you have problems in your select query. Please show the code

Comment: @Steve : My select query is fine. May be,Problem is in the selection of database. I have edited my question please see..

Comment: Absolute path for connectionstring is not acceptable for me like Data Source=C:\Company\Software\TSM_DB.sdf;.....Please suggest, what should i do ?

Comment: No, the SELECT seems correct. I suppose the insert use the same connection, so are you sure that the insert is successfully? Could you show the code for the INSERT method?

Comment: ** My problem: When I try to insert data into the database it gets inserted to the database present in Debug folder and not in the database which is included in the project... ** This is how it is supposed to work with |DataDirectory|. If you want to deploy your project with populated database, you need to copy the populated database in your project.

Answer (score 3):

> When I try to insert data into the database it gets inserted to the database present in Debug folder and not in the database which is included in the project...

Which is exactly what you told it to do, and is what you want. The database in your project folder is part of the source code. When you test or debug your code, the data changed is part of your test or temporary debug output, not your source code.

When you test your code, would you want the test overwriting your source code? I hope not, that would destroy your source; and when you deploy your project you don't usually deploy your source code. The same is true of your data; the data in your project is part of your application and is **not** the end-user data. When you install your application your source data gets installed to `DataDirectory`, which is part of your application and is not user data; the user may not even be able to write to it.

When you uninstall or update your application, `DataDirectory` gets uninstalled or updated. You don't want to do that to your user's data; would you like it if every time you updated Microsoft Word it deleted every Word file on your drive? That's what would happen if Word stored user data in its equivalent of `DataDirectory`.

`DataDirectory` is only for your app's private use. If a user needs this data you should copy it to a user-writable place that won't get deleted, like `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.

Further explanations at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13998558/22437).